# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException (Microsoft Bot Framework)

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

Am new in Bots , i registered my bot and i tried to run it on the Emulator **Microsoft Bot Framework Channel Emulator (3.0.0.59)** and also i tested it on **Test connection to your bot**, but am getting this error on both of them , which is as below :

```
500 InternalServerError
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'huzy281116'
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Intercom.DevPortal.Server.Controllers.BotManagerController.<PingV3BotAsync>d__73.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\DevPortalLib\Controllers\BotManagerController.cs:line 2039
```

I did all the necessary steps like inserting the **BotId**, **MicrosoftAppId**, and **MicrosoftAppPassword**.

Why is this error coming is there any new way of doing this , because this is my first run Bot App.

Comment: Is huzy281116 a valid remote name?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain, what do you mean by a valid remote and how can i make it a valid remote name please , coz ma new in this

Comment: I thought the bot is running on the localhost , so please how can i make it right , because even i don't understand by making a valid remote name

Comment: Try searching for what remote name is.

Comment: Ok boss, but it would have been better if you tell me the steps

Comment: Your bot and emulator might not be compatible versions. It isn't necessary to register your bot, or have a MicrosoftAppId or MicrosoftAppPassword to locally test your bot with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer , i had to leave the **Microsoft App Id** and **Microsoft App Password** blank on the Emulator , and i tested it after running the project.

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the latest Bot Framework Channel Emulator from here: https://emulator.botframework.com  (at v3.5.25 as of 2017.03.05)

[image]